# need to pause my program with a timer in java

Tags: java, timer

Can someone just show me the code id need, in the timer class, to sort of pause my program, just have the timer run for a few seconds with nothing happening. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us the code what you've done till yet?

Comment: Like the `sleep()` method?

Comment: Okay maybe I should rephrase this I need a timer to run but with no code. so literaly just a timer block with no code I cant figure it out.

Comment: "*Can someone just show me the code id need*" No. Show effort

Answer (score -1):

You can pause execution of any thread (timer executes your timertask in a background thread) with Thread.sleep(int ms).

More details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html